# How can I get the last item in every list from a column of lists in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column of lists in a dataframe in R that I got from simply splitting pagepaths by "/".

`search_console_data$page_title_ <-  str_split(search_console_data$page, "/")`

I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to derive the last item from each list into a seperate column or the same one. I'm looking to isolate the page title from url. The dataframe  looks like this:

| 1 | page_title_ |
| --- | --- |
| a | c("https:", "", "www.x.com", "") |
| b | c("https:", "", "www.y.com", "") |

I've seen solutions like this:
`rev(x)[1]`
`x[length(x)]`
and wasn't sure how to apply correctly.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The canonical is (as akrun shows) `tail(x, 1)`, one (much faster) alternative being `x[length(x)]`; both of those would be the `...` portion of `lapply(yourframe, function(x) ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

As it is a `list`, use `lapply/sapply/map` to loop over the `list` and get the `last`

```
df1$new <- sapply(df1$page_title_, tail, 1)
```

If the last element is blank (`""`), subset to return the non-blank last element

```
df1$new <- sapply(df1$page_title_, \(x) tail(x[x != ""], 1))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(new = map_chr(page_title_, last))
```

non-blank last element

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
        mutate(new = map_chr(page_title_, ~ last(.x[.x != ""])))
```